tailwind group class problem using Angular
when i was creating my program i tried to used the group class function in tailwind. suprisingly it doesn't work. than i decided a new program and added this code :
<div class="tw-group tw-p-6 tw-bg-white tw-border tw-border-gray-200 tw-rounded-lg">
  <h2 class="tw-text-xl tw-font-bold tw-mb-4 tw-group-hover:tw-text-blue-500">Parent Component</h2>
  <button class="tw-group-hover:tw-bg-blue-500 tw-p-2 tw-bg-blue-300 tw-rounded">Hover me</button>
</div>

i set up a prefix which is 'tw-' at the tailwind.config.js file. the group class still doesn't work. then i tried to delete the prefix and also change all the class with the beginning "tw-". to my suprise the group class function worked as expected.
can anyone help me fix this problem? because i want to use the prefix

As per the documentation:

It’s important to understand that this prefix is added after any variant modifiers. That means that classes with responsive or state modifiers like sm: or hover: will still have the responsive or state modifier first, with your custom prefix appearing after the colon:
<div class="tw-text-lg md:tw-text-xl tw-bg-red-500 hover:tw-bg-blue-500">
  <!-- -->
</div>


So for your situation, your group-hover: classes should be group-hover:tw-text-blue-500 and group-hover:tw-bg-blue-500:


tailwind.config = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div class="tw-group tw-p-6 tw-bg-white tw-border tw-border-gray-200 tw-rounded-lg">
  <h2 class="tw-text-xl tw-font-bold tw-mb-4 group-hover:tw-text-blue-500">Parent Component</h2>
  <button class="group-hover:tw-bg-blue-500 tw-p-2 tw-bg-blue-300 tw-rounded">Hover me</button>
</div>



